# How can I suppress error output from grep, so that it only returns the exit status?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, error-handling, centos

Is it possible to grep the following error and suppress it so it will come as output of 1 or 0?

"0" for this error is exist and "1" for not.

```
yum repolist | grep -q 'Error: rpmdb open failed'
rpmdb: Thread/process 2329/140564164429728 failed: Thread died in Berkeley DB library
error: db3 error(-30974) from dbenv->failchk: DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
error: cannot open Packages index using db3 -  (-30974)
error: cannot open Packages database in /var/lib/rpm
CRITICAL:yum.main:

Error: rpmdb open failed
```

I want to run it in script, so it will check if this error is occurred or not, if so it will handle it with the correct actions .

Comment: The problem is that error messages are not passed through the pipe by default, and are instead shown directly on console. Use `|&` or `2>&1` to let `grep` look at errors as well.

Comment: yum repolist 2>/dev/null | grep -q "Error: rpmdb open failed"

Comment: managed to do it with |&
like the following :
`yum repolist |& grep -e 'error: db3 error' ; case "$?" in "0") echo "match" ;; "1") echo "no match" ;; *) echo "error" ;; esac`

thank you guys :)